# How to select rows where a combination of 2 columns is the same

Tags: sql, postgresql

The title seems to do a really poor job at describing my problem; let me try and explain it with a simplified example:

lets say I have the following table:

```
_______________________
|id|variant_id|attr_id|
|__|__________|_______|
|1 |15        |110    |
|2 |15        |110    |
|3 |20        |152    |
|4 |20        |110    |
|5 |21        |110    |
|__|__________|_______|
```

Now, what I'd like to have is a query that selects all rows where a combination of the `variant_id` and `attr_id` columns occurs more than once. Basically in this example it should select row 1 and 2, because their combination of `variant_id` and `attr_id` occurs more than once in the table.

Is that possible? My head hurts from trying to think of a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
tbl a 
inner join 
tbl b
ON a.variant_id =b.variant_id AND a.attr_id = b.attr_id
WHERE a.id <> b.id;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: AH of cause! I forgot you could join tables on themselves! Thanks this work flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT variant_id, attr_id
FROM YouTable
GROUP BY variant_id, attr_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```