# Select rows where column 1 value is the same but column 2 value is different in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on PostgreSQL on a table with this structure :

```
________________
|project|person|
|_______|______|
|1      |P1    |
|1      |P2    |
|2      |P3    |
|2      |P3    |
|3      |P4    |
|_______|______|
```

I would like to write a SQL query to select ONLY the rows where one project has more than one person. In other words, I would like to select all the rows where the project is the same but the person is different, excluding the other rows. In my example it would return only the two first rows :

```
________________
|project|person|
|_______|______|
|1      |P1    |
|1      |P2    |
|_______|______|
```

I can not wrap my head arround this. Is saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273427/how-to-select-rows-where-a-combination-of-2-columns-is-the-same) which is basically the opposite but I don't see how to make it work for me.

I tried to fiddle with COUNT or HAVING for a long time but I can not grasp the logic of how I should build this query. For example I tried :

```
SELECT t.person, t.project
FROM table t
GROUP BY r.ide_proj, r.ide_pers
HAVING COUNT(t.person) > 1
```

but this gives me strange results, including rows whre one projects only has one person, or vice-versa.

Can somebody help me with this little problem ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Can't you add the expected result too? And show us your current query attempt!

Comment: did you try something like this : `select * from YOURTABLE having count(person)>1 ` ?

Comment: @Alainlb `count(Distinct person) > 1`  project 2 had p3 twice.

Comment: Tried `SELECT t.person FROM table t HAVING count(Distinct t.person)>1 ;` however I got an error saying t.person needs to be in a GROUP BY clause. When I add `GROUP BY t.person` the query doesn't give an error but I don't have any rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery to get the `distinct` rows and then a `window function` to get both the `project` and the `person`.

```
select * 
from (
    select *, count(person) over (partition by project) cnt
    from (select distinct project, person from yourtable) t 
    ) t
where cnt > 1
```

---

Or you could use a regular `group by` query, but you'll need to `join` the result back to the original table to get the names associated with each `project`.

```
select t.*
from yourtable t join (
    select project 
    from yourtable
    group by project 
    having count(distinct person) > 1) t2 on t.project = t2.project
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! :) I'll keep working on these queries to make sure I understand them.

Thanks to everyone who answered too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is the count(Distinct person) > 1

```
Select project, person 
from table 
group by project 
having count(distinct person) >1
```